# Removing extra column separator in automated table header row command

Tags: tables

I create a lot of tables in my work and I frequently find that my header row code can get quite cumbersome to read, especially as I like `\textbf{}` and use mathematical notation too.

I have got this far, but I am having trouble removing the final `&`, which means I always get an extra row. Can someone help please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tabHeader}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }{\textbf{{##1}} & }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc|ccc}
\toprule
\tabHeader{A, B, C, D, E, F, G}\\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tabHeader}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \textbf{##1} }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { & }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc|ccc}
\toprule
\tabHeader{A, B, C, D, E, F, G}\\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]